Integrate Cassandra and JetBrains Expose
I need to integrate Cassandra into a Kotlin Ktor application. JetBrains' Exposed is getting a lot of traction, but Cassandra is not listed as supported. Ktorm also looks OK, but it does not list Cassadra.
Is there a way to integrate Cassandra into Exposed or Ktorm? Or is there any other similar framework?
